# Why I don't have available operators Voximplant?

Tags: javascript, voximplant

I'm trying to write a simple call center in this example: https://voximplant.com/blog/acd-call-queuing

I created queue and skill group, but I don't have available operators:

http://joxi.ru/DrlvZkzsvMZK62

Also, when I try to call to my call center `ACDEvents.Offline` always fire up, how it's possible to solve?

Comment: How are we supposed to know? You haven't shown any code and the one thing you've provided relating to your implementation is in Russian.

Comment: May you have experience with that library already, what is problem?

Comment: Even if I did how would I know what *your* problem is with *your code* if you don't show *your code*?

Comment: Do you know about that system, there I don't need to show any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is much better "Call center" tutorial available [here](https://voximplant.com/blog/step-by-step-call-center-tutorial).

Modern programmable platforms like Voximplant greatly simplifies telephony, but there are still lots of things to do. "Operator" is a user that connects cloud telephony via a web interface (assumed that you will write your own, but phone.voximplant.com will do for a debug purpose) or SIP. "Offline" means no one is connected and logged in yet!

Comment: Thx, so much for your comment, I'm understand, like after auth of Operator we need to change status of him through API, can we programmatically change Skill group?

Comment: Yes, everything can be changed via HTTP API. Although, for complex scenarios (where you need to change skill group programmaticaly) it's highly recommended to implement your own call distribution via your own backend logic.